# Different Variance formula confusion

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, discrete-data

I couldn't find a specific thread that discusses this, but I was wondering why the difference between these 2 formulas for Variance

$\frac {\sum (x-\mu )^{2}}{N} $

and

$\sum (x-\mu )^{2} p(x)$

I can understand that the bottom equation applies to discrete distributions where we know the entire population and it's probability of values. But in the case of the 1st equation, are we dividing by N because the probability of getting any single variable in the continuous normal distribution(or if it's a discrete distribution with equal probabilities) is equally likely(despite the fact that PDF for random variables closer to the mean is higher in a normal distribution)?

Comment: Notice that $\mu$ must have a different formula in the two cases.  In the first instance, $\mu= \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{N}x_i.$  In the second instance $\mu=\sum_{i=1}^N p(x_i)x_i.$ The role of $p(x_i)$ is played by $1/N$ in the first formula, making it a special case of the second. This has nothing to do with Normal distributions or pdfs.

Answer (score 0):

The first equation is for finding the variance of a finite population of values.

The second equation is where you have a probability distribution function.

For the population of finite values you could consider $p(x) = \frac1N$ and the 2 equations become the same.

But more often the first is used when you have data values, e.g. The number of student enrolled at each 4-year college or university in the US.  The population here is all the colleges and universities and you have a value for each one which you can use to calculate the population mean and variance.

For the second equation we are looking at a distribution, e.g. we know that the number of calls to a particular call center per hour follow a Poisson distribution with mean of 23.  We can use the formula for the Poisson distribution and the second formula to find the variance for the number of calls per hour.